# Comma in the decimal numbers (Italian notation)

Tags: fonts, packages, siunitx, punctuation, mtpro

I wanted to ask this question a few months ago, and I don't know if there is a duplicate. I have searched but couldn't find anything. Here there is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[ 100 \text{ metri} - (13 \text{ metri} + 76,50 \text{ metri}) \]
\[ 100 \text{ metri} - 89,50 \text{ metri} \]
\[ 10,50 \text{ metri} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Assuming that I don't want to use `siunitx` package, why is there one too many spaces between the integer part and the decimal part when I use the comma?

With the `mtpro2` package, lite version, the space is more prominent.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,eurosym}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\[ 100 \text{ metri} - (13 \text{ metri} + 76,50 \text{ metri}) \]
\[ 100 \text{ metri} - 89,50 \text{ metri} \]
\[ 10,50 \text{ metri} \]
\end{document}
```

> Is there a solution or trick? Addendum: If I use the fullstop like comma all work very well.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [`icomma`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/icomma) or [`textualicomma`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textualicomma) or [`decimalcomma`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/decimalcomma)

Comment: @mbert Perfect with icomma. +1.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer yourself

Comment: Off-topic: I don't think the comment "Required for including letters with accents" applies to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`; instead, it would apply to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. `utf8` is the default input encoding nowadays; hence, there's actually need to run `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` unless you're running a very very old TeX distribution.

Comment: @Mico Hi, I have understood. Thank you vey much to you and mbert.